# export -f equivalent in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I just joined a new team and the environment setup script uses `export -f` commands inside it. Even though there's a bash shebang at the top, it seems like the `export` command being called is the one from zsh and so the `-f` option doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this or am I obligated to use bash?

Comment: [linux - How to export a function in ksh ? Without global declaration or using autoload - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049208/how-to-export-a-function-in-ksh-without-global-declaration-or-using-autoload)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zsh doesn't support exporting functions and very likely never will. It is not a clever feature as was made plain by the shell shock bug a few years ago. Function autoloading is a better approach.

Environment setup files typically have to be sourced - inlined in an existing shell instance so the shebang is ignored. It'd be better to persuade your team to stick to portable features. Functions could be but aside in a directory and sourced for bash or autoloaded for zsh.

Or if really necessary create a temporary function wrapper for export to ignore -f, use `disable export` source the bash setup and then reenable zsh's export.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ended up here because Google decided this was the "best result" the accepted answer is more opinionated than helpful. I was going to mark this as a duplicate, but the answer found was on unix stackexchange. @davidpostill also posted this in the question, but I typically cruise down to the answer section immediately. [The real answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59360/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-export-f). It also contains a link to the wiki about shell shock bug from 2014 that is still not fixed.